Denominational views of whether scripture is the literal word of God, or the authors' words as inspired by God
In Did John misread the Septuagint? - Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange, we have conflicting views:

… given our belief that Christ dictated the book [of Revelation] …

and:

… the vision was from Jesus, but the words were not necessarily dictated, rather they could have been John's own words of what he observed in that vision.

What is the division of beliefs among the various denominations regarding scripture?:

The text was literally dictated by God (or holy agent).
The text was the writers' words (except where explicitly stated. E.g. Revelation 2:1's "Unto the angel of the church of Ephesus write; …"), as inspired by God.
The text contains sacred truths, but also human opinions etc.
The text originates solely from the human imagination.

Note that I'm not asking which view is correct, only about which major denominations hold which views.
Also, I would hope the last category is empty, but it won't be surprising if it isn't.

I don't think anyone that would call themselves "Christian" would fall into the "text originates solely from the human imagination" category... For that matter, even many atheists would affirm that Scripture contains (at least some) true history. For example, few would argue that Jesus is merely a figment of the authors' imaginations.

@Matthew, agreed. But I had to include it just to be sure. I've seen large respected denominations that barely mention anything specifically religious. For instance, the largest Protestant denomination here is the United Church, and my local United Church of Canada's web site comprises 50+ pages, yet the word "Jesus" appears only once in only one of them, and that's in the boiler-plate preamble to the annual report. Similarly the word "Bible" appears only once, and that's about "bible study" and is merely a link to another page that of course doesn't mention anything about it.

I am uncertain if your third category would include the idea that the Bible 'contains' the word of God, but proponents of this saying are actually stating that nobody can be precise about what the 'word of God' actually is. Presumably - therefore - nobody may voice a particular portion of scripture in the expectation that anyone will believe it or, indeed, obey it.

I'm not sure what the difference is between these two understandings of Biblical authorship practically speaking, in either case the Word of God is faithfully being recorded by human hands. If I show you a movie and ask you to describe it, is that sufficiently different than me dictating the summary I want you to write? How much the less does it matter when God had foreknowledge of what the authors would write, and showed them what they needed to see in order for their writings to convey what He meant to be recorded?

The belief that the Bible was literally dictated word for word by God is extremely rare in Christianity.
Virtually all Christian denominations adhere to the belief that God inspired the authors of the Bible to write what they did using their own words. It is certainly true of all mainstream denominations. This does not contradict the idea that Scripture is infallible - it means that God inspired the writers infallibly.
Some parts of the Bible were dictated by God, and the authors recorded them. For example the Ten Commandments. But that's not true of the whole Bible.
The belief expressed in the question you linked to is that of an individual. The questioner says "our" but doesn't indicate a group that believes this. It is not uncommon to find people who believe that God dictated the Bible, even when their church leaders would disagree.
For more details on the exact nature of inspiration, see this answer.

Also probably worth noting... Paul sometimes identifies statements as "my teachings, not Christ's", yet I suspect many Christians hold those in equal esteem. (Compare to Ray's third category.)
